# C#/.NET + VisualStudio, namespace problem

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I have started learning C#/.NET/VisualStudio (2022) and have this strange problem; all the methods/classes in System and it's nested namespaces seem to be available **without** full path or using directives at beginning.

E.g. the following example compiles just fine:

```
// Program.cs
namespace MyApp
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!"); //System.Console
        }

        static HttpClient client = new HttpClient(); //System.Net.Http.HttpClient
    }
}
```

Why this happens and can I disable this behavior somehow?

Comment: This is likely from the new feature in .NET 6 called "implicit usings" https://dotnetcoretutorials.com/2021/08/31/implicit-using-statements-in-net-6/ https://www.hanselman.com/blog/implicit-usings-in-net-6

Comment: Search your entire project for this string: `global using System;`

Comment: @jmoerdyk Thanks, that was it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using .NET 6, this is likely from a new feature called "Implicit Usings".   Depending on your project type, certain namespaces are automatically included.  For example, the default console app template implicity includes the following namespaces:

- System;
- System.IO;
- System.Collections.Generic;
- System.Linq;
- System.Net.Http;
- System.Threading;
- System.Threading.Tasks;

You can disable this feature by including the following in your project file:

```
<PropertyGroup>
   <ImplicitUsings>disable</ImplicitUsings>
</PropertyGroup>
```

There is further documentation on this feature and "Global Usings" [in this Microsoft documentation.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tutorials/top-level-templates)

Answer (score 0):

You are using [implicit global usings](https://dotnetcoretutorials.com/2021/08/31/implicit-using-statements-in-net-6/?series). Change the lines in your `.csproj` files from

```xml
<ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
```

to

```xml
<ImplicitUsings>disable</ImplicitUsings>
```